# Copy selected CSS style between DIVs by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to copy some CSS styles form one DIV, to another DIV.

1. Click on the "ONE" DIV
2. Then jQuery read list of CSS properties from ARRAY
3. Then copy these properties from DIV "ONE" to DIV "TWO".

This is my attempt, but it does not work. What's wrong with it?

["JsFiddle Example"](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/meU9M/1/).

HTML

```
 <div class="one">Click HERE on this DIV, to TRANSFER CSS properties From this ONE</div>
 <div class="two">To this TWO</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
   background-color:gray;
}
.one {
   color: red;
   font-size:12px;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: white;
   margin: 20px;
   padding: 20px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.two {
   font-size:20px;
   color: blue;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: yellow;
   margin: 20px;
   padding: 20px;
}
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("div.one").click(function(){
         var $array = ['color','width','height', 'background-color', 'font-weight', 'font-size'];
         $(this).each( $array , function(item, value){
             $("div.two").css(value, $(this).css(value));
         });
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select [**`jQuery`**](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js) at the left panel of JSFiddle.
   [image]
2. Use [`$.each(array, fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) instead of [`$().each(array, fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
3. Store `$(this)` in a variable, eg `$this = $(this)`. Inside the loop, `this` refers to the array element, *not* to the DOM element which is clicked.
4. (non-critical) Do not prefix non-jQuery objects with a `$`.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/meU9M/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.one").click(function(){
        var array = ['color','width','height', 'background-color', 'font-weight', 'font-size'];
        var $this = $(this);
        $.each( array , function(item, value) {
            $("div.two").css(value, $this.css(value));
        });
    });
});
```